# How does serialization work in Java if an object is upcast before serialization?

Tags: java, serialization, rmi

Say I have an interface and an object:

```java
public interface MyInterface {
    public String getStringOne();
}

public class MyObject implements MyInterface {
    private final String stringOne = "string1";
    private final Image myGiganticImage; // loads from disk in the constructor

    // Getters for both would follow
}
```

What gets transferred if I upcast MyObject to MyInterface before sending it across the wire?

```java
public class MyService {
    private final MyObject data = new MyObject();

    public MyInterface getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

Specifically, does `myGiganticImage` get sent across the wire?

Comment: If you look at `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Object)` you will see that all references are up cast to Object before serialisation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously the state of `MyObject` is serialized. `public MyInterface getData()` just enforces that the type returned by `getData()` is-a `MyInterface`.

Comment: So, if I want to reduce the amount of data going across the wire, I need to create a new object, right?  I updated my question.  What you're saying is, in my updated example, `myGiganticImage` **would** get sent across the wire, right?

Comment: Every field that's not `transient` and not `static` will be serialized (unless there is a [custom `writeObject(ObjectOutputStream)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) method taking care of things) -- serialization doesn't care about the type/class/interface of the object being serialized as long as it implements `Serializable`

Answer (score 1):

Upcasting doesn't change the content of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Upcasting is just a way to change pointer type. The same data structure kept on your JVM heap regardless pointer type. This structure really does not care about the way you point to it.

When you serialize object system (probably) would ask your object for class (getClass()) and then read all fields from this class using reflection. 
Object would always report its class even if you point to it using *Object*.

System will always read fields from class because it is the only way in java to get list of fields: ask object for class and than ask class for fields.

If you want to transfer object's parent you may try my solution: [Deserialize remote object to the narrowest accessible class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249569/deserialize-remote-object-to-the-narrowest-accessible-class/10253094#10253094)