# Akka Remote and interception of unknown classes through custom deserialization

Tags: java, class, serialization, akka, akka-remote-actor

**Problem/Context**. I need to send some messages to a remote actor. These messages may contain objects of a class that is unknown on the recipient side. And I need to intercept such a situation in order to avoid a ClassNotFoundException.

**One solution** may consist in intercepting unknown classes at the time of message deserialization. Then, the message may be replaced by a different application-level message so that the remote actor can communicate to the sender that it doesn't have the required classes.

I don't know if such an interception is possible, because custom de/serializators must implement akka.serialization.Serializer which has the following method

```
def fromBinary(bytes: Array[Byte],
               clazz: Option[Class[_]]): AnyRef
```

Now, the problem stems from the construction of the Class objects (which is done from Akka) for objects of an unknown class.

Is there a way to customize Akka deserialization at a lower-level point in order to accomodate my needs?

**Other solutions**.

- The problem is similar to the one depicted in the following SO question, where a different solution has been proposed: [Deserialize remote object to the narrowest accessible class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249569/deserialize-remote-object-to-the-narrowest-accessible-class)
  It would still be useful to have an answer there. However, that solution wouldn't be sufficient for me, because while it would be ok to restrict the interface, I would still need a class implementation with extra methods.

Comment: probably you might want to check out `kryo`.

Comment: @Nik could you also explain why? To my understanding Kryo is just a serialization framework. Does it have some specific features that do help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FACT 1.** Actually I discovered that there is an alternative to deserialization with Class type hint, namely **deserialization with string manifest**. Reference: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.0/scala/serialization.html#Serializer_with_String_Manifest

NOTE: it is NOT available for Akka < 2.4.0. It might matter as from Akka 2.4.0 support for Java 1.6/1.7 is dropped. This means that to use Akka 2.4 you are required to have Java 8.

**FACT 2.** I also discovered that you Akka does not necessarily provide you the type hint. You can disable the type hint in the following way

```
class MyOwnSerializer extends akka.serialization.Serializer {
   override def includeManifest: Boolean = false // !!!
```